# How to define Attributes like background colour

Tags: python, html, email

How we can give background colour or any other tags on row and column in this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways to set background-color property using inline CSS, internal CSS and external CSS,

```html
<div style="background-color: red">
```

also you can apply this to your table row and as well as on table column like below.

```html
<tr style="background-color: red">Table row</tr>
<td style="background-color: green">Table Column</td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).